# What design pattern is good for applying attributes to a class that changes its behavior?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am trying to find the best way to structure my project. What I would like to do is have a "Structure", which is made of multiple "part". These parts also will have separate attributes, for example it could be spinning, hovering, vibrating, jumping, shaking, growing, accelerating.

So for example, I might have a "structure" called human that is made of 6 "parts". I am going to set each part to one of the available options, so in this case, 2 parts are going to be arms, 2 parts are going to be legs, one part is a torso, and one part is a head. Now, I want to be able to apply the attribute spinning to one of the parts, the arm. So now I should have a human with a spinning arm.

Additionally, I would like other people to be able to create their own cusom attributes, structures, and parts.

I would like to get an idea on how I should structure my code, and apply an attribute to a part. Additionally, what design pattern would be good for this?

Comment: This seems just to be about organizing your abstract concepts (pure oop), something like `Entity`, which can be a parent to another entity (now, this relationship can be named, not just parent: something like entity->'contains'->entity). The same thing can be done with attributes. If you have 'entity types', these types can pre-define attributes. And this can be modeled using data, which will make it extensible.

Comment: So should a structure contain an array of parts that contains an array of attribtues. and every type of attribute has its own constructor?

Comment: Define your attributes as enum {SPINNING, HOVERING, ...}. Enum can have members either and also getter. For each part, create a list of attributes the part has. The client code can set attributes to each part by adding to this list. Or a Map if you like, so you can lookup whether a part has a given attribute.

Comment: @Lini That won’t work.  Enum constants are static.  A setter method would change the attribute for *all uses* of that constant.

Comment: @VGR, right, i corrected this. Enum can has getter only and is not dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requirement is to have a single interface for a composition of various objects / components.

There are 2 suitable design patterns for this requirement.

1. Facade (https://dzone.com/refcardz/design-patterns?chapter=17)
2. Composite Object (https://dzone.com/refcardz/design-patterns?chapter=15)

Facade pattern can be used when the way in which the internal components are assembled must be abstracted.

Composite object pattern can be used when the assembly of the components must be advertised.